# Google Guava MultiMap I don't know how to get access to my objects

Tags: java, collections, guava

I created a hashmultimap
How can I use iterator to get access to my Student objects inside hashmultimap?

```
Multimap<Integer, Object> myMultimap2 = HashMultimap.create();
Student one = new Student("Bob","Any",35);
Student two = new Student("Tom","Johnson",22);
Student three = new Student("Yo","Zun",42);
myMultimap2.put(1,one);
myMultimap2.put(2,two);
myMultimap2.put(2,three);
Iterator<Integer> iterator = myMultimap2.keySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
    int key = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(key);
    Collection collection = myMultimap2.get(key);
    Iterator iterator2 = collection.iterator();
    while (iterator2.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator2.next());
        ???????
    }
}
```

Comment: So you figured that this class exists; and you read the documentation on howto insert things, but you are unable to read the documentation that tells about retrieving values? Just wondering ...

Answer (score 1):

Guava's `Multimap` keeps a `Collection` of values for each key.
So, the `Object` returned by your second iterator `iterator2` is actually your `Student` that you put earlier.

Perhaps it would make more sense for you to use proper generics, i.e. declare your `Multimap` as `Multimap<Integer, Student>`. Then your second iterator would return `Student` instead of `Object`.